# I do not want the derived class to inherit the constructor function of the Base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

As it is located at the title.

**Here is example:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
private:
    int nSize;

public:
    Base(){
        cout << "I'm Base constructor" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    int nMaxSize;

public:
     Derived(){
        cout << "I'm Derived constructor" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Derived obj;

    return 0;
}
```

**The result:**

```
I'm Base constructor
I'm Derived constructor
```

Comment: The base class constructor will always be called when creating an object of a derived class that is how inheritance works. Maybe composition would be a better choice here.

Comment: Derived objects have to construct their Base counterparts some way.

Comment: If Base isn't root of hierarchy and it's applicable to you...you may **consider** to use **virtual inheritance**, you'll skip parent's constructor and _root_ constructor will be called. That said if you need something like this just **do not use inheritance** at all (something is **bad in that design**, it may be a flag to indicate it's time to **refactor** or to **search for a different approach**).

Comment: @Borgleader: Composition does not solve the problem, since also members have to be constructed. The problem is not inheritance. It's a misunderstanding of the construction process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no choice. The best you can do is pass a flag to the base constructor disabling what you don't want. But this indicates bad design.